# Understanding peer dependency error for an npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package.json

I'm trying to understand a peer dependency error from an npm package.

The error:

```
Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-test-renderer@18.2.0
node_modules/react-test-renderer
  dev react-test-renderer@"^18.2.0" from the root project
  peer react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/jest-native@5.1.2
  node_modules/@testing-library/jest-native
    dev @testing-library/jest-native@"*" from the root project
```

I understand that `@testing-library/jest-native@5.1.2` depends on `react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0"` - basically a version of `react-test-renderer` equal or higher than version 16.0.0. So why am I getting this peer dependency error if the package version installed fulfills the requirement?

Comment: have the exact same problem with jest and react testing library and wondering the same thing. Were you able to figure out why you keep getting this error?